# snapshot.data[0] throwing "The Method '[ ]' cannot be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, future

Also getting

```
Try making the call condtional (using ?.) or adding a null check to the target
```

for the same line(s):

```
Text("${snapshot.data[index]}")
```

If I do that I get only the error message from the title.

I have actually copy/pasted a FutureBuilder from another project of mine where it is working perfectly fine but in this one I get this error. The only difference is that in the not working project I see this:

```
AsyncSnapshot<Object?>
```

and in the working project I see this:

```
AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>
```

If I hover over `snapshot`

The entire section looks like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: http_functions.myAsyncFunction(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Scrollbar(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    thickness: 4,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text("${snapshot.data[index]}"),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
```

While `myAsyncFunction()` returns a `List<dynamic>` using return `json.decode(response.body);`

Comment: you are seeking for [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the type parameter of the FutureBuilder. And cast the snapshot.data to not null by using the `!` operator

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: http_functions.myAsyncFunction(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Scrollbar(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    thickness: 4,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: 10,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text("${snapshot.data![index]}"),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
```

Comment: Defining the parameter worked. Thank you!

Comment: Very annoying that even though you checked snapshot.hasData, it doesn't automatically promote snapshot.data to non-nullable type (due to snapshot.data being a property, and can't be promoted.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `snapshot.data?.docs?[0].data()`. It will return the value if not null and return null otherwise.

Comment: Tried it already but that did not work. The error message from the title remains

Answer (score 0):

In `AsyncSnapshot<Object?>` the object is nullable which means it can have a value or can be null. Now you are accessing the object like `snapshot.data[index]`. Here the `snapshot.data` can be null and accessing index of a null array can cause error.

So in order to access your array safely  replace `snapshot.data[index]` with `snapshot.data?[index] ?? ''` or you can use the null assertion operator like this if you are sure that your list can't be null `snapshot.data![index]`.